# find and replace with sed with slash in find and replace string

Tags: sed, quoting

I want to change in file `/var/www` with `/home/lokesh/www` with `sed` command

```
sed -i 's///var//www///home//lokesh//www/g' lks.php
```

but this give error

```
sed: couldn't open file ww///home//lokesh//www/g: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Not sure if you know, but `sed` has a great feature where you do not need to use a `/` as the separator.

So, your example could be written as:

```
sed -i 's#/var/www#/home/lokesh/www#g' lks.php
```

It does not need to be a `#` either, it could be any single character. For example, using a `3` as the separator:

```
echo "foo" | sed 's3foo3bar3g'
bar
```

Comment: if you're using sed to insert lines after or before a match, you don't use `s/` but just `/` and with this you can use / in your replacement string.
`sed -i '/^.*my.match.pattern.*$/i \    <logger name="my.replacement.pattern" level="DEBUG"/>' logback.xml`

Comment: If you're on a Mac, `brew install gnu-sed` and use `gsed` instead of `sed`

Comment: Lovely. Helped a lot

Answer (score 13):

You can use a different character for the delimiter, as others have pointed out, like this:

```
sed -i 's!pattern!replacement!g' /path/to/file
```

But if there is no convenient character to use instead of `/` as the delimiter, you can also escape any embedded delimiter characters in your `pattern` and `replacement` by prefixing them each with a backslash `\`. Here's an example using `/` as the delimiter that replaces `/some/path` with `../some/replacement`:

```
sed -i 's/\/some\/path/..\/some\/replacement/g'
```

It's harder for humans to read, though, so generally if it's at all possible it's better to use a different character for the delimiter like this:

```
sed -i 's!/some/path!../some/replacement!g'
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you try to use something like:

```
sed -i 's@/var/www@/home/lokesh/www@g' lks.php
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put a simple premat command in front of the sed command in the bash script, which masks the slash in path variables.
Let's assume the path variable to be swapped is in $P0:

```
P0="/foo/foo/foo/file"; 
P0=(${P0////\\/});  #masked Slash to form: \/foo\/foo\/foo\/file
```

Should be exchanged with:

```
P1="/whatever/youwant/file"; 
P1=(${P1////\\/}); #masked slash to form \/whatever\/youwant\/file
```

With sed simply afterwards:

```
sed -i "s/${P0}/${P1}/" /wherever/that/should/go/file;
```

This works in bash --version 5.1.4(1)

Comment: IMHO best way to go with random output strings, except if they contain spaces.