# I want find a word and replace it with new a new word in a new line

Tags: sed

Like :

```
sed 's/</risk_measure_slice>/</risk_measure_slice>\n/g' allinoneline1.mqf
```

Which is not working

Comment: What is your input, what is your expected output, and what is your observed output? (But it looks like you are trying to replace nothing.)

Comment: @Sparhawk That was due to bad formatting.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. I can't change my close vote now, but that means it's a dupe, e.g. of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378990/find-and-replace-with-sed-with-slash-in-find-and-replace-string) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382077/replace-a-string-including-a-slash-using-sed-command) and probably more…

Comment: @Sparhawk We don't know what's "not working", so the `/` delimiters may only be part of the issue here. Once fixed, the command may well still do the wrong thing... A vote to close as "unclear" is still correct IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression and your replacement text contains `/`.  This is also the character used by `sed` as the delimiter in its `s` command.

This means that you will have to either escape your `/`, as in

```
sed 's/<\/risk_measure_slice>/<\/risk_measure_slice>\n/g' allinoneline1.mqf
```

or use another delimiter, as in

```
sed 's#</risk_measure_slice>#</risk_measure_slice>\n#g' allinoneline1.mqf
```

or shorter,

```
sed 's#</risk_measure_slice>#&\n#g' allinoneline1.mqf
```

Note that your replacement text contains `\n`.  This will be interpreted as a newline only by GNU `sed`.  If using BSD `sed`, this character will be outputted as `n`. The standard syntax supported by GNU `sed`, BSD `sed` or any POSIX-compliant `sed` would be:

```
sed 's#</risk_measure_slice>#&\
#g' allinoneline1.mqf
```

If using GNU `sed` and if you'd like your XML end tag on a new line, then the `\n` should precede the tag, not come after it.

You may also want to look into tools for formatting/modifying/querying XML files, such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or similar.